# How to add story to top of pivotal tracker backlog with API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pivotaltracker

I've got two situations, either high or low priority.

High-pri should go to top of backlog. low-pri should go to top of icebox.

In order to send something to top of backlog, you have to add `current_state=unstarted` and `before_id=[id of first item in backlog]`

getting the first item in backlog is a simple fetch to the `/stories?limit=1&current_state=unplanned` except this request on average seems to take 10-15 seconds!

Am i going about this incorrectly?